# Runtime Error Exemption as been thrown by the Target of an invocation

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I am new to SSIS and C#. I have been working on a project to read file information from directories and store in a SQL table. I have multiple directories and was able to use script task to read information from 4 directories. The 5th directory is throwing me the "Runtime Error Exemption as been thrown by the Target of an invocation" error. I added Messagebox.show to navigate the issue but I observed that the package runs into this error abruptly without being thrown at a zip folder or an empty folder.

Please review my code:

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
        //MessageBox.Show(myADONETConnection.ConnectionString, "ADO.NET Connection");
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = myADONETConnection;


        string DirPath = Dts.Variables["User::VarDirectoryPath"].Value.ToString();

        //get all files from directory
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, "*"); /* Using "*" to identity any zip folders and read file information from them */

      if (Directory.Exists(DirPath))
        {
            string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(DirPath, "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string foldername in folders)
            {
                string[] fnames = Directory.GetFiles(foldername);
                foreach (string filename in fnames)
                {

                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);

                    sqlCmd.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.FileInformation_6 Values('" + file.FullName + "','" +
                     file.Name + "','" + file.LastAccessTime + "','" + file.CreationTime + "','" + file.Length / 1024 + "')";
                    //MessageBox.Show(sqlCmd.CommandText);

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }            
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("InComplete");
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Please let me know if you could help me with it.

Thanks,
Dhipthee Pujar

Comment: Without knowing more details about the exception we can't help you. It sounds like we need to see the `Message` and `StackTrace` of the `InnerException` property of the exception object.

Comment: Side notes: You need `using` blocks on the ADO objects. You have SQL injection problems here. You should specify the column names you are inserting into. You should consider just using `SqlBulkCopy` instead of looping an `INSERT` command, which will be much faster

Answer (score 0):

I was able to navigate and resolve the issue.  My code was being thrown off for multiple reasons:

1. I had created my table with Character limit to 150- I changed that to 255.
2. If it encountered a filename with " or '- I renamed such files.

Thank you